# access master router from a pc via a mid router placed inbetween PC and master router

Tags: router, routes

I have 2 routers, Master router which is ADSL broadband modem/router (192.168.0.1). which is connected to a telephone ISP. then a Mid router which has Wan port connected to the master router's lan port(192.168.0.2) and Its LAN port is configured as 192.168.1.1 and it provides dhcp server as 192.168.1.x as ip and 192.168.1.1 as gateway.

I am able to connect to the internet from 192.168.1.10 with router as 192.168.1.1.

My question is i want to access the master router which is (http:// 192.168.0.1) from 192.168.1.10.

I want it to be stacked. dont want to end up with single flat network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't "stack" up Network Address Translating (NAT) routers like that.

Disable the DHCP server on the "Mid router" (sic) and configure it with a static IP address *other* than 192.168.1.1 in the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet. Connect it to a LAN port on the "Master router" (sic).

This will eliminate a redundant NAT step and an unnecessary DHCP server. You'll end up with a single "flat" network and you'll be able to access the user interfaces of both routers (the "Master" at 192.168.1.1, and the "Mid" at whatever IP address you assign to it).

---

Edit:

Change the network addressing on the "Mid router" (sic) LAN network to some subnet other than 192.168.1.0/24. Then you will be able to access the "Master router" user interface.

Comment: thanks evan, previously i used like that. but i just want to explore more with routers and route. i am expecting a answer like adding a route to my system or use tunnel like that. i want it to be stacked.

Comment: thanks evan, that worked. i tried with 10.1.1.0/24. but why it doesnt work with 192.168.1.0/24